# Play individual videos one after the other no break - youtube, or?

Tags: jquery, flash, youtube

I am working on a project where there will be vidoes of words in english ( just a video of someone saying a word) and I would like to put the videos together to make a sentence so that they play one after the other. Using youtube playlists the videos have a pause in between that is way to long. I basically need to have the one video playing as soon as the other one finishes. Is there a way to do this in youtube?

Or perhaps be best to just upload the videos onto my site? If anyone has done something like this any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way how to achieve the behaviour you want is to use flash videos like on this site http://www.miccam.com/. It sounds that they have done exactly what you want. The only other way I can think of would be to load several youtube videos on a site and use a chromeless player with JS controls to play them in a sequence. That would eliminate the loading process...

Update: Click on the VIDEO VOCABULARY link on the site or use this link http://your.miccam.com/index.php#/HOME/

Comment: Awesome thanks. that is basically the site I was thinking of making ha.

Comment: :) you're welcome... I went to school with the guy that made it so that's why I know about them...